# Cannot combine initializer list with inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, initializer-list

I have some code where I would like a class instance to be able to initialize a variable in its initializer while also calling in its initializer list the parent class constructor. This parent class constructor would initialize three extra variables in its own constructor's initializer list.

Here some code that uses these constructor on a different class:

```
class Vec3f {
public:
  inline Vec3f () : x (0), y (0), z (0) {}
  inline Vec3f (float xx, float yy, float zz) : x (xx), y (yy), z (zz)  { }
private:
  float x,y,z;
};

class Vec4f : Vec3f {
   public:
      inline Vec4f (): Vec3f(), w(0) {}
      inline Vec4f (float a,float b,float c,float d): Vec3f (a,b,c), w(d) {}
private:
    float w;
};

class Matrix4x4 {
   public:
      void setIdentity ();
    private:
      Vec4f row1, row2, row3, row4;
};

void Matrix4x4::setIdentity () {
  row1 (1.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
  row2 (0.0f,1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
  row3 (0.0f,0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);
  row4 (0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
}


main () {
   Matrix4x4 a;
   a.setIdentity ();
}
```

When I run the above code, I receive:

```
test.cpp: In member function ‘void    Matrix4x4::setIdentity()’:
test.cpp:26: error: no match for call to ‘(Vec4f) (float, float, float, float)’
test.cpp:27: error: no match for call to ‘(Vec4f) (float, float, float, float)’
test.cpp:28: error: no match for call to ‘(Vec4f) (float, float, float, float)’
test.cpp:29: error: no match for call to ‘(Vec4f) (float, float, float, float)’
```

In another message board someone suggested this:

```
class Vec3f {
public:
  inline Vec3f () : x (0), y (0), z (0) {}
  inline Vec3f (float xx, float yy, float zz) : x (xx), y (yy), z (zz)  { }
  inline void Set3f (float xx, float yy, float zz) {
    x = (xx);
    y = (yy);
    z = (zz);
  }
private:
  float x,y,z;
};

class Vec4f : Vec3f
{
   public:
     inline Vec4f (): Vec3f(), w(0) {}
     inline Vec4f (float a,float b,float c,float d): Vec3f (a,b,c), w(d) {}
     inline void Set4f (float a,float b,float c,float d) {
     Set3f(a,b,c);
     w = d;
     }
   private:
     float w;
};

class Matrix4x4 {
  public:
    void setIdentity ();
    Matrix4x4() :
      row1 (1.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f),
      row2 (0.0f,1.0f,0.0f,0.0f),
      row3 (0.0f,0.0f,1.0f,0.0f),
      row4 (0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f)
   {}
  private:
     Vec4f row1, row2, row3, row4;
};

void Matrix4x4::setIdentity () {
  row1.Set4f(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
  row2.Set4f(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
  row3.Set4f(0.0f,0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);
  row4.Set4f(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
}


int main () {
  Matrix4x4 a;
  a.setIdentity ();
}
```

However, this seems a hack for me. Don't want to call two setter method. Better to just do what I need in a normal constructor, less code. So I ask: Why c++ does not allow the constructor initializer list to work the way I want?

Answer (score 2):

You are not using the constructor's initializer list in `setIdentity()`, that is why your code is failing.

`Vec4f` does not implement an `operator()` (the [function call operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_function_call_operator)), so statements like

`row1 (1.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);`

inside of `setIdentity()` don't work, and besides they don't do what you think they do anyway.

You likely meant to construct new `Vec4f` instances and assign them to the existing variables, eg:

```
void Matrix4x4::setIdentity () {
  row1 = Vec4f(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
  row2 = Vec4f(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
  row3 = Vec4f(0.0f,0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);
  row4 = Vec4f(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
}
```